# Not able to get correct date value in javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, date

[I have updated this question below, please see new question on infinite looping of alert]

I have a date of birth field in my form and there is an input field as well as date picker.

After keying in the correct value, the change function is activated and runs the logic as below to do some processing to the date of birth to get age.

However, when I use `alert()` to prompt for the value of the date of birth, I am not able to see the value I keyed in reflected, instead, it is showing an empty string.

I tried `document.getElementById("9_element14").value`, but that didn't work, it showed undefined. So I switched to `jQuery` and now it shows empty string.

It is a Wordpress form maker form, so there is restriction in amending the HTML, but I can change the JavaScript.

Any advice is much appreciated.

The link to the form is here:
http://lionfish.vodien.com/~scforgsg/RC7/menu-parent-courses/course-application/

My codes are as below:

HTML

```
<tr id="9" type="type_date"><td valign="middle" align="left" id="9_label_section14" class="">
<span id="9_element_label14" class="label">Date of Birth:</span>
<span id="9_required_element14" class="required"> *</span></td>
<td valign="middle" align="left" id="9_element_section14" class=" toolbar_padding"><input type="hidden" value="type_date" name="9_type14" id="9_type14">
<input type="hidden" value="yes" name="9_required14" id="9_required14">
<input type="text" value="" class="wdform_date" id="9_element14" name="9_element14" maxlength="10" size="10" onchange="change_value('9_element14')">
<input id="9_button14" type="reset" value="..." format="%d-%m-%Y" onclick="return showCalendar('9_element14' ,'%d-%m-%Y')" class="button">
</td>
</tr>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 // before form is load
function before_load()
{   

}   


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id$=11]').hide();
    $('[id$=49]').hide();
});

// before form submit
function before_submit()
{

}   
// before form reset
function before_reset()
{   
}

function on_choose_course() {
 var course = document.getElementById("1_element14");
var selected = course.options[course.options.selectedIndex].value;
if (selected=="Canoe Polo Lvl 1" || selected=="Kayaking Orientation" || selected=="1 Star Award"){
       $('[id$=49]').hide();
}
else{
       $('[id$=49]').show();
 }


}

$(function(){
$('[id$=9_element14]').change(function(e) {
       on_date_select();
    });
});

function ValidateDate(dtValue)
{
var dtRegex = new RegExp(/\b\d{1,2}[\-]\d{1,2}[\-]\d{4}\b/);
return dtRegex.test(dtValue);
}


function on_date_select() {
//calculate age
var current_year = new Date().getFullYear();

if ($('[id$=9_element14]').length) {
var dob = $('[id$=9_element14]').val();

alert($('[id$=9_element14]').val());

if (ValidateDate(dob)){
var age = current_year - substr(dob, 6, 10);
alert(substr(dob, 6, 10));
alert(age);

if (age<21){
//show declaration is 21 and above
   $('[id$=11]').show();
}

if (age>=21){
//show declaration is 21 and above
   $('[id$=11]').hide();
}
}//end validatedate
}//end check empty
}
```

==================================================================

Thanks guys for helping! Using jsfiddle and making changes here and there, I derived the conclusion that the way I was using substring for dob was not working, causing the whole function to fail.

So now I have corrected it. Only problem now is that I am getting an infinite looping of alerts when date of birth is invalid.

NEW CODES:

```
// before form is load
function before_load()
{   

}   


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id$=11]').hide();
    $('[id$=49]').hide();
});

// before form submit
function before_submit()
{
  checkDetails($('[id$=15_element140]'),$('[id$=21_element14]'));
}   
// before form reset
function before_reset()
{   
}

function on_choose_course() {
 var course = document.getElementById("1_element14");
var selected = course.options[course.options.selectedIndex].value;
if (selected=="Canoe Polo Lvl 1" || selected=="Kayaking Orientation" || selected=="1 Star Award"){
       $('[id$=49]').hide();
}
else{
       $('[id$=49]').show();
 }

}

function checkDetails(e,f){
 if (e.checked && (f.trim()).length==0){
   alert("Please give details about the medical condition.");
   e.focus();
 }
}

$(function(){
$('[id$=9_element14]').change(function(e) {
       on_date_select();
    });
});

function ValidateDate(dtValue)
{
var dtRegex = new RegExp(/\b\d{1,2}[\-]\d{1,2}[\-]\d{4}\b/);
return dtRegex.test(dtValue);
}


function on_date_select() {
//calculate age
var current_year = new Date().getFullYear();

if ($('[id$=9_element14]').length) {
var dob = $('[id$=9_element14]').val();

if (ValidateDate(dob)){
var age = current_year - dob.substring(6, 10);

if (age<21){
//show declaration is 21 and above
   $('[id$=11]').show();
}

if (age>=21){
//show declaration is 21 and above
   $('[id$=11]').hide();
}
}else{
$('[id$=9_element14]').focus(
function() {
alert("Date of Birth is invalid");
}
);
}//end validatedate
}//end check empty
}
```

Comment: I had copy your code and put it here, http://jsfiddle.net/vXZuL/, it work fine, there have another code that hit the error

Comment: Thank you Se0ng11. I didn't see what was wrong with my code either, it could be the date picker causing some conflict and problem. The thing is that there should be another alert on the DOB year and age later on, but there are no more alerts.

Comment: the jsfiddle did not include all the script that you had included in your web, so maybe you can update the jsfiddle and post it here again and see if we can find and squeeze the bugs in your script, and the other alert is not popping out because `change_value('9_element14')` is not define

Comment: Dear Se0ng11, I have updated http://jsfiddle.net/vXZuL/10/ with the other functions called, can you help to take a look? I don't know where you see the log in jsfiddle, so I cannot debug.

Comment: You can try to test the date of birth field on the actual site here: http://lionfish.vodien.com/~scforgsg/RC7/menu-parent-courses/course-application/ I tried to do some changes, but as of the last I tried, after the alert comes out and I click ok, another of the same alert comes, the whole browser hangs. So it seems like someone the field is calling itself again and there is infinite looping.

Comment: You can use google chrome or firefox, and bring up the developer tools by pressing `f12`, I had see yours real site, but is hard to debug for you as I can't add debugger into your real site, so the only way is to put it in jsfiddle, as in the new jsfiddle you just update, `showCalendar is not defined`, `change_value is not defined `, your script is missing this 2 function

Answer (score 2):

The `ID` and `NAME` tokens **must begin with a letter** `([A-Za-z])` and **may** be followed by any number of letters, digits `([0-9])`, hyphens `("-")`, underscores `("_")`, colons `(":")`, and periods `(".")`.

Change your element identificators according the rules and everything will work.

More information [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2).

Comment: Thank you bodi0. However, I do not have the luxury of changing the ID and NAME tokens as they are assigned by the plugin I am using (not written by me). Other javascript codes however are working, I just don't understand how come this one is not, there may be some conflict with the date selector.